# How do I make my Python Script into an Executable .dmg file for Mac?

Tags: python, macos, kivy

Right now, I have a python script that when run, opens up a python window using a package "kivy", while processing data using many other packages. Is there a way for me to combine all of these into a .dmg file that when run, installs all the necessary packages and launches the python application as a .app file?

Know there's a lot of factors and this is really specific, but any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: Why to not use [`setup.py`](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use `py2app` - https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

[Here's](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-with-pip) some installation instructions.

And [here's](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) a small tutorial because why reinvent the wheel - they explain it well, it's a really simple process.

Comment: You forgot the *.dmg part I think. To do this, make a new folder and put your *.app inside. Then, open Disk Utility, and go into File->New Image->Image from folder, and select your folder. This should create a *.dmg file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [py2app](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to do this.